# Hatch lines using turtle to fill polygons

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle
import math

def getPolygonVertices(numVertices): #get polygon vertices function
    vertices = []
    for i in range(numVertices):
        x = int(input(f"Enter x coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
        y = int(input(f"Enter y coordinate of vertex {i+1}: "))
        vertices.append((x, y))
    return vertices

def polygon(vertices): #draw polygon function
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])
    turtle.down()
    for vertex in vertices:
        turtle.goto(vertex)
    turtle.goto(vertices[0])

def pointInsidePolygon(point, vertices): #function to check if a point is inside polygon
    x, y = point
    inside = False
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        j = (i + 1) % len(vertices)
        if ((vertices[i][1] > y) != (vertices[j][1] > y)) and \
           (x < (vertices[j][0] - vertices[i][0]) * (y - vertices[i][1]) / (vertices[j][1] - vertices[i][1]) + vertices[i][0]):
            inside = not inside
    return inside

def hatchPolygon(vertices, line_spacing=10, angle=0):
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()

    #draw polygon
    polygon(vertices)

    #compute and draw hatch lines
    min_x = min(v[0] for v in vertices)
    max_x = max(v[0] for v in vertices)
    min_y = min(v[1] for v in vertices)
    max_y = max(v[1] for v in vertices)

    #convert angle to radians
    radAngle = math.radians(angle)

    #compute line spacing in x and y direction
    line_spacing_x = lineSpacing * math.cos(radAngle)
    line_spacing_y = lineSpacing * math.sin(radAngle)

    #compute start point
    start_x = math.floor((min_x + line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) * line_spacing_x
    start_y = math.floor((min_y + line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y) * line_spacing_y

    #compute end point
    end_x = math.ceil((max_x - line_spacing_x/2) / line_spacing_x) * line_spacing_x
    end_y = math.ceil((max_y - line_spacing_y/2) / line_spacing_y) * line_spacing_y

    #draw hatch lines
    turtle.penup()
    for y in range(int(start_y), int(end_y), int(line_spacing_y)):
        for x in range(int(start_x), int(end_x), int(line_spacing_x)):
            if pointInsidePolygon((x, y), vertices):
                turtle.goto(x, y)
                turtle.pendown()
                turtle.goto(x - line_spacing_x * math.tan(radAngle), y + line_spacing_y)
                turtle.penup()

    turtle.done()


#Main
n = int(input("Enter number of polygon vertices: ")) #get number of vertices 
polygonVertices = getPolygonVertices(n) #get polygon vertices

#hatch line 
lineSpacing = 10
angle = 45
hatchPolygon(polygonVertices, lineSpacing, angle)
```

Above is my code for drawing parallel lines to shade a polygon. However, my lines extend outside the border of the polygon with this code.

My output:

[image: my output]

I'm unsure of where the error is in calculating the start and end points. The result I am expecting is something like this:

[image: expected result]

If there is any error elsewhere do let me know.

Comment: Having `input()` makes it hard to reproduce. I suggest hardcoding your test case and adding the input at the end so you don't have to keep typing it. I think this one is something like `(0, 0), (100, 100), (100, -100)`.

Comment: As for you algorithm, looks like the step size is too large. By the time you detect that the turtle is outside of the polygon, it's already drawn outside of it. `inside = not inside` also looks suspicious--usually, once you determine you're inside or not inside, that's the final determination. Otherwise, you could flip the result back and forth and just return whatever the last check happened to set it to.

Comment: Are you supposed to handle concave shapes?

Comment: @ggorlen hi thanks for the help but  the project brief mentions that the user should be able to put in relevant inputs or read from a file to get the polygons and it also mentions the polygons can be concave or convex

Comment: Of course, but during development, it's easier to hardcode your input temporarily so you can iterate quickly and make your test case reproducible to others. It's trivial to add whatever UI input is necessary at the very end, before you turn it in. Otherwise, you'll spend a good portion of your development time typing the same thing into the terminal over and over. Thanks for clarifying the concave--that eliminates a number of alternate approaches.